# :hover not working with pull-right or pull-left classes

Tags: html, css

For some reason, using pull-left and pull-right classes in my HTML prevents :hover and ng-click from working. I would like to add the pull-left class to #mobile-nav #logo and the pull-right class to #mobile-nav p, so that they stay in the same line and stay to the left and right of the mobile nav menu, respectively, regardless of the width of the menu. However when I add pull-left or pull-right classes, the :hover pseudoclass stops working on #logo and both #logo and p lose the ng-click functionality. I cannot for the life of me think why (the same thing happens when I remove pull-left and pull-right, adding float:left and float:right instead).

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="mobile-nav" ng-if="$ctrl.mobileNav">
  <div id="logo">
    <a ng-click="$ctrl.mobileNav = false;" href="#welcome"><h1>A N S A R O</h1></a>
  </div>

  <p ng-click="$ctrl.mobileNav = false;">X</p>

  <ul class="-mobile-nav-menu">
    <li><a ng-click="$ctrl.mobileNav = false;" href="#about" du-smooth-scroll>About</a></li>

    <li><a ng-click="$ctrl.mobileNav = false;" href="#" du-smooth-scroll>Blog</a></li>

    <li><a ng-click="$ctrl.mobileNav = false;" href="#team" du-smooth-scroll>Team</a></li>

    <li><a ng-click="$ctrl.mobileNav = false;" href="#jobs" du-smooth-scroll>Jobs</a></li>

    <li><a ng-click="$ctrl.mobileNav = false;" href="#contact" du-smooth-scroll>Contact</a></li>          
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #199EB8;
}

#mobile-nav #logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#mobile-nav #logo h1 {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mobile-nav #logo h1:hover {
  color: #111;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
}

#mobile-nav #logo img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#mobile-nav p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mobile-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#mobile-nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

#mobile-nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 22px 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}

#mobile-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #111;
}

#mobile-nav ul li li {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Any thoughts/fixes would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I assume they are special classes used by whatever plugin you got? You should be able to figure why this isn't working by inspecting the element and turning the hover option on. The css should tell the story. My guess is `pointer-events: none` might be set on it from the plugin

Comment: Okay from inspector I can see that forcing hover on the elements changes the color but I still can't get any response to clicking on them...

Comment: adding {pointer-events: all} or {pointer-events: auto} doesn't seem to change it either unfortunately

Comment: If there isn't any css on it to prevent it from working then it must be the js. I don't know how that plugin works but it most likely disables click so it can drag but i guess it cannot distinguish between a click and a drag

Comment: Got it! I had to set {display: inline-block} on my #logo element so that it wouldn't extend across the entire nav menu and cover the p element... I think this was preventing me from being able to hover/click on the p element.